# how can i render a template string like “<div>{{mydata.value_name}}</div>” in realtime with vue3

Tags: vuejs3

How can I render a template string like `<div>{{mydata.value_name}}</div>` in realtime with vue3

The data `mydata` I can definition dynamic

```
<script setup>

let dynamicCom 

http.post("/someGate",(res)=>{

    // when i get response ，i can initial the component dynamically
    dynamicCom.template = "<div>{{mydata.value_name}}</div>"
    dynamicCom.data = {
      mydata:{value_name:"jim"}
    }
})

</script>

<template>    
   <dynamicCom/>    
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to dynamically update some value, then Vue reactivity is enough. Just make your `mydata` reactive

```
const mydata = reactive({ value_name: "jim" })
```

If you want to render your component content dynamically, then you should use Vue [Render Functions & JSX](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx)

### Here is a simple playground to demonstrate both ways

```js
const { createApp, h, reactive } = Vue;

const MyComponentA = {
  setup() {
    const mydata = reactive( {value_name: "jim"} );
    return { mydata } 
  },
  template: `
  <div>
     <input v-model="mydata.value_name" @update="mydata.value_name == $event.target.value" />
     <div>value_name: {{mydata.value_name}}</div>
   </div>`
}

const MyComponentB = {
  setup() {
    const mydata = reactive( {value_name: "jim"} );
    return () => 
          h('div', null,
            [
              h('input', { 
                  value: mydata.value_name,
                  'onInput': (event) => mydata.value_name = event.target.value
              }),
              h('div', null, `value_name: ${mydata.value_name}`)
             ]
          )
   }
}

const App = { components: { MyComponentA, MyComponentB } }
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <b>Vue Reactivity</b>
  <my-component-a></my-component-a><hr/>
   <b>Vue Reactivity & Render Functions</b>
  <my-component-b></my-component-b>
  
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```